# Eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So suppose we have one matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1& 0\\ 2& 3&1&0\\ 3&4&5&1\end{bmatrix} $$

If we write this matrix as the sum of two matrices $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1& 0\\ 2& 3&1&0\\ 3&4&5&1\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0& 0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 1& 0\\ 2& 3&0&0\\ 3&4&5&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Where the matrix with 1's down the diagonal we could call $M_1$ and the second matrix $M_2$ where $M=M_1+M_2$. Instead of finding the eigenvalues of $M$ could we just find the eigenvalues of $M_1,M_2$ instead and work with that? I understand we could just find the eigenvalues of the original matrix, but for when the matrix has worse/variables for entries.

Comment: If $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are eigenvalues of $M_2$ then $a_1+1,a_2+1,a_3+1, a_4+1$ are eigenvalues of $M_1+M_2$. The reverse is also true. $M_2$ and $M_1+M_2$ have the same eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us fix some notation first.

Define
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1& 0\\ 2& 3&1&0\\ 3&4&5&1
\end{bmatrix}, \ \
M_1 =  I, \ \ 
M_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 1& 0\\ 2& 3&0&0\\ 3&4&5&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly,
$$
M = M_1 + M_2
$$

Let $(\lambda, \mathbf{x})$ be any eigenpair for $M_2$.

Then it follows that
$$
M_2 \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x} \tag{1}
$$
Also,
$$
I \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} \tag{2}
$$

Adding (1) and (2), we get
$$
(I + M_2) \mathbf{x} = (\lambda + 1) \mathbf{x}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
M \mathbf{x} = (\lambda + 1) \mathbf{x}
$$

If $(\lambda, \mathbf{x})$ is an eigenpair for $M_2$, then $(\lambda + 1, \mathbf{x})$
is an eigenpair for $M$.

Thus, the eigenvalues of $M$ are given by
$$
\lambda_1 + 1, \lambda_2 + 1, \lambda_3 + 1,  \lambda_4 + 1
$$
where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$ are the eigenvalues of $M_2$. Moreover, $M$ and $M_2$ have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: ah interesting. Technically if $M_1 \neq I$ this would still hold where the eigenvalues of $M$ would be $\lambda_1 +1,..., \lambda_4 +1$? Edit: Nvm I answer my own question in asking that one.